# Embed iframe - Youtube video not looping

Tags: javascript, html, video, iframe, youtube

in one of my page i've got this situation:

```js
<script>
                    /* 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
                    */
                    var tag = document.createElement('script');

                    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

                    /* 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player) after the API code downloads.
                    */
                    var player;
                    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                      player = new YT.Player('player', {
                        videoId: 'xbiEN3jGi00',
                        events: {
                          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                        },
                        playerVars: { 
                            'autoplay': 1,
                            'loop': 1,
                            'controls': 0, 
                            'rel' : 0,
                            'showinfo': 0,   
                        }
                      });
                    }

                    /* 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.*/
                    function onPlayerReady(event) {
                      event.target.playVideo();
                      player.mute();
                    }

                    /* 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
                   The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
                   The player should play for six seconds and then stop.
                    */
                    var done = false;
                    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                      if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING ) {
                          player.playVideo(); 
                      }
                    }
                </script>
```

```html
<div class="video-background-container parallax embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" data-stellar-ratio="0.4">
      <div id="player" class="embed-responsive-item"></div>
    </div>
```

> The 'player' div is the target of the youtube embed video api javascript.
>   My problem is that the option 'loop' doesn't work for my
>   video.

Where is my mistake?
What option should i set?

Thanks in advance for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data != YT.PlayerState.PLAYING ) {
        player.playVideo();
    }
}
```

Using `!=` (not equal to) instead of `==` (equal to)